# android xml reference not working with switch and case with static array

Tags: android, xml, reference, static, for-loop

I'm trying to make my life a heck of a lot easier by cycling through buttons in my xml (because I have a ton of buttons).  Why isn't this working?

```
Button bf[];
public static final int[] Buttons = { R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4,
        R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7, R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.bBack,
        R.id.bClearAll, R.id.bClear };
```

I have a static final int that holds some of my buttons, which is list in the header.
Within my onCreate method I set up my buttons:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        bf[i] = (Button) findViewById(Buttons[i - 1]);
        bf[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Nice and easy right? but then when I try to reference them in the switch and case (within my implemented onClickListener method, I'm having problems:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        case Buttons[i-1]:
            Toast.makeText(this, bf[i].getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
```

This doesn't work, so then I just tried a single reference:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case Buttons[0]:
        Toast.makeText(this, bf[1].getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
```

which doesn't work either?!?!  Help please?

Comment: 12 in the array, but you stop at 10, i < 10. and arrays start at 0 not 1. try i = 0, i < 11, i++

Comment: Well I think all of my buttons are set up (i know not all of them, but enough to test out the application)  The error comes in within the switch and case, I don't know how to cycle through all of my buttons simply.  Eclipse is giving me an error in both of the last two code blocks I posted. :/

Comment: On the last code block it gives me an error on Buttons[0] = "case expressions must be constant expressions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v is your View in the onClickListener, right?
Why don't you use:

```
Button b = (Button) v;
Toast.makeText(this, b.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Some other points:

- You did not post the complete code but I guess you can change your Buttons array to private.
- Probably you don't even need bf[]

Edit: Also I'd suggest to use this for-loop to cycle through all of your buttons to make it more flexible:

```
for (int i : Buttons) {
    Button b = findViewById(i);
    b.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
```